# steam crashes on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: steam, 20.10

When I run Steam on Ubuntu 20.10 it says "verifying installation" and then suddenly it crashes with no error messages. I didn't have this problem on 20.04. Here's the logs report.

```
[2020-10-24 13:48:21] Startup - updater built Oct 23 2020 20:26:36
[2020-10-24 13:48:21] Loading cached metrics from disk (/home/humble-mouse/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2020-10-24 13:48:21] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2020-10-24 13:48:21] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2020-10-24 13:48:21] 1. http://client-download.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'baked in'
[2020-10-24 13:48:21] 2. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2020-10-24 13:48:21] Checking for update on startup
[2020-10-24 13:48:21] Checking for available updates...
[2020-10-24 13:48:21] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2020-10-24 13:48:23] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1603487799, installed version 1603487799, downloaded version 0
[2020-10-24 13:48:23] Nothing to do
[2020-10-24 13:48:23] Verifying installation...
[2020-10-24 13:48:23] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2020-10-24 13:48:24] Verification complete
```

Comment: I would recommend LTS versions for gaming. Don't use non-LTS releases for gaming. LTS tend to be more stable and have better software support for them.

Comment: What is the source of the steam installation? Can you post the output from the terminal when you try to run steam?

Comment: This worked for me:- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346437/steam-crashes-silently-on-startup-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-20-04-igpu/1346451?noredirect=1#comment2300860_1346451

Answer (score 2):

When this happened to me I found disabling the auto submit of the password worked. I set the `rememberPassword` flag to zero in the config file `~/.steam/registry.vdf` using nano.

I submitted a similar issue a few days ago so it seems like the latest update broke Steam on Ubuntu for a lot of people.

[Steam crashes silently on startup on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 (igpu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346437/steam-crashes-silently-on-startup-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-20-04-igpu/)

Comment: This fixed it for me! Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it using

```
sudo aptitude install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

I don't really know what `aptitude` is, I think it's just a different kind of interface to `apt`, but it managed to solve all the problems with unmet dependencies I had when I tried to install `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` using `apt`.
After this, I ran

```
sudo apt install steam
```

and I started Steam via terminal. It installed the other dependencies and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

We will win!
Try to follow the known path

```
sudo su
dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
If there is no i386 architecture dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt update
apt-get install -f
```

A very useful command that lists all the dependencies that a package has, including recommended packages.

- apt-cache depends steam

  or https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/steam
  The most common problem that needs to be fixed manually is:
  sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

If the problem persists

```
apt-get install --reinstall steam
This is a package groovy steam (1:1.0.0.61-2ubuntu3) [multiverse]
```

If the problem persists

```
sudo apt purge steam
```

and

wget -O ~/steam.deb https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/client/installer/steam.deb

sudo apt install -f ./steam.deb

Answer (score 0):

I found these helpful commands. They fixed the crashing issue for me (installing 32 bit driver).

```
nvidia-smi | grep "Driver Version"
```

You will get the following dialogue

```
NVIDIA-SMI 460.73.01 Driver Version: 460.73.01 CUDA Version: 11.2
```

Run the following command to install 32 bit driver

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-460:i386
```

460 is the driver version.

Hope it helps :)
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

nothing of the proposed things here worked for me

however what did the trick was:

```
steam --reset
```