# Steam crashes silently on startup on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 (igpu)

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, steam

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T440s on which I was previously running Ubuntu 18.04 and now Ubuntu 20.04.

One day last week Steam just stopped working. It performs verification as normal and then just stops. When I launch it from terminal I get the following output:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/user/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam -nominidumps -nobreakpad
[2021-06-17 10:42:19] Startup - updater built Jun  8 2021 22:23:36
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2021-06-17 10:42:19] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2021-06-17 10:42:19] 1. https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'update_hosts_cached.vdf'
[2021-06-17 10:42:19] 2. https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'update_hosts_cached.vdf'
[2021-06-17 10:42:19] 3. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2021-06-17 10:42:19] Checking for update on startup
[2021-06-17 10:42:19] Checking for available updates...
[2021-06-17 10:42:19] Downloading manifest: https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2021-06-17 10:42:20] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1623193086, installed version 1623193086, existing pending version 0
[2021-06-17 10:42:20] Nothing to do
[2021-06-17 10:42:20] Verifying installation...
[2021-06-17 10:42:20] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-06-17 10:42:20] Verification complete
STEAM_RUNTIME_HEAVY: ./steam-runtime-heavy
```

And then it silently dies. I have tried updating to Ubuntu 20.04, reinstalling steam, updating drivers etc. (every other solution I found on here which are mostly to do with dedicated graphics cards misbehaving). Reinstalling steam would work once and then this problem would reappear when I closed steam and attempted to re-open it.

Does anyone have any insight into this problem or a work around for launching tabletop sim (the only game I play on this machine). I really really don't want to totally wipe the machine and reinstall the OS since this is also my work machine since the pandemic started and I don't want to have to reinstall all my ssh keys, dev software etc.

Thanks

**Update**

The `error.log` file in `~/.steam/debian-installation` reports the following:-

```
nstalling breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Loaded SDL version 2.0.15-6501165
Gtk-Message: 11:31:50.628: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 11:31:50.628: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:23234): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:31:50.631: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/main.rc:775: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'

(steam:23234): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:31:50.632: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadAtom (invalid Atom parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
Atom id in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  12
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadAtom (invalid Atom parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
Atom id in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  13
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadAtom (invalid Atom parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
Atom id in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  14
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
[0617/113151.042040:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(247)] Crash reporting enabled for process: browser
[0617/113151.062779:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0617/113151.062852:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1623191035
[0617/113151.062858:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0617/113151.062862:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
[0617/113151.102489:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0617/113151.102562:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1623191035
[0617/113151.102568:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0617/113151.102573:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
[0617/113151.104725:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(247)] Crash reporting enabled for process: gpu-process
[0617/113151.134901:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(372)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[0617/113151.169299:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0617/113151.169369:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1623191035
[0617/113151.169375:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0617/113151.169379:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
[0617/113151.170013:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(247)] Crash reporting enabled for process: utility
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
CApplicationManagerPopulateThread took 0 milliseconds to initialize (will have waited on CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 111 milliseconds to initialize
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
Proceed to auto login
src/public/tier1/utlmemory.h (176) : Assertion Failed: 0
src/public/tier1/utlmemory.h (176) : Assertion Failed: 0
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
crash_20210617113151_22.dmp[23331]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20210617113151_22.dmp
src/public/tier1/utlvector.h (1216) : Assertion Failed: !pArray || (Base() >= (pArray + size)) || (pArray >= (Base() + Count()) )
src/public/tier1/utlvector.h (1216) : Assertion Failed: !pArray || (Base() >= (pArray + size)) || (pArray >= (Base() + Count()) )
src/public/tier1/utlvector.h (1208) : Assertion Failed: count >= 0
src/public/tier1/utlvector.h (1208) : Assertion Failed: count >= 0
double free or corruption (!prev)
assert_20210617113149_1.dmp[23334]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20210617113149_1.dmp
/home/user/.steam/debian-installation/steam.sh: line 772: 23234 Aborted                 (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER $DEBUGGER_ARGS "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
crash_20210617113151_22.dmp[23331]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
crash_20210617113151_22.dmp[23331]: response: CrashID=bp-9536b9bc-be97-4003-ae61-4bc482210617
crash_20210617113151_22.dmp[23331]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20210617113151_22.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-9536b9bc-be97-4003-ae61-4bc482210617''
assert_20210617113149_1.dmp[23334]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20210617113149_1.dmp[23334]: response: CrashID=bp-ffdda10e-c1ba-4dbd-acf2-feaa92210617
assert_20210617113149_1.dmp[23334]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20210617113149_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-ffdda10e-c1ba-4dbd-acf2-feaa92210617''
```

Comment: Check if there is a log file with more details; possibly in  `~/.local/share/Steam` or maybe in `~/.steam`.

Comment: What graphics are you using? Intel? Nvidia? If it's hybrid (i.e. both of them on demand), any chance to set this fixed to NVidia in the BIOS?

Comment: Also check available RAM and swap (`free -h`). If it's running low, check if you have a browser open with lots of tabs; and if yes, close a few dozen tabs. ;-)

Comment: I have 11Gig of free RAM so its not an issue with RAM usage, I have no dedicated graphics card so it would be Intel HD Graphics 4400. I've found a folder called `logs` in `~/.steam/debian-installation` but I'm not sure which file I'm looking for

Comment: Ah-ha. I've found a file called `error.log` which seems like the place to look and I'll add it's reports to the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reportedly it's fixed in the current Steam beta:

https://www.gamingonlinux.com/2021/06/latest-steam-client-beta-improves-proton-startup-times-fixes-login-issue

https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/7813

To enable the beta, go to the 'Steam' menu at upper left, then on the 'Account' panel under "Beta participation" it should show "Not participating (1 currently available).  Change that to "Steam Beta Update", and then restart steam.  You should then get the Updating Steam dialog, and then prompt to log in.  Turn "Remember my password" back on.  Moment of truth:  Now exit out of steam, and restart and see if it comes back normally (spoiler - it worked).

Answer (score 3):

The answer posted by HuHa has led me to this thread:
https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/3106901028662477002/?ctp=2
Which provides the solution of editing the config file at `~/.steam/registry.vdf` to set the `RememberPassword` flag to 0. This will mean that you have to enter your password every time you start Steam but will allow Steam to start and not just crash every single time. I have no idea what is going on here but this work around will allow me to keep playing games with my friends until the lockdowns finally end. I think this might have been introduced in the last update to Steam since it worked one day and not the next so it might not be needed forever.

Comment: Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

So you have several different things going on in that error log.

I have no idea if those messages *Failed to load module "gail"* and *Failed to load module "atk-bridge"* have any significance; since they are logged as *Gtk-Message* and not *Gtk-Error* or *Gtk-Warning*, they are probably harmless.

The *Gtk-Warnings* about the *adwaita* theme are very likely also harmless.

But those *X Error* messages may be a real problem: *BadAtom* used to be one of those messages in low-level X11 programming that spelled doom; in particular with *Atom id in failed request:  0x0* which (IIRC) means passing an invalid / null X atom ID.

And this is (AFAICS) the cause for the next messages about uploading a crash report which also fails.

Those messages *src/public/tier1/utlvector.h (1216) : Assertion Failed* come from a piece of Valve (i.e. Steam) software as far as I can tell; this might be a consequence of previous errors.

So Steam tried to do low-level X11 calls, and at least some of them failed.

[Which begs the question: Are you even running X11, or is it Wayland? You can check with `xdpyinfo` (from package *x11-utils*).]

**Edit:** `xdpyinfo` doesn't throw an error, so it's indeed X11.

Comment: I think X11, I can't see any mention of Wayland in `xdpyinfo`. I can see `version number:11.0` and `vendor string: The X.Org Foundation`

Comment: If `xdpyinfo` doesn't throw an error, you definitely have X11.

Comment: I am fresh out of ideas.

Comment: Ok, Your comment about he X11-utils being the source led me to the solution I am about to post. This is insane