# Steam crashes on 21.04

Tags: xorg, steam

I don't use steam very often, but know it worked previously on this machine. Recently it's stopped working, crashing on launch. I'm running Kubuntu 21.04 on X11 (not wayland). Things I have already tried:

- Reboot
- Ensure I am up to date via `apt`
- `steam --reset` - which gets steam working for one launch, then fails on next launch
- Remove steam and reinstall `steam-installer`
- Ensure I have i386 arch enabled

Running `steam` in a terminal produces a [large log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/tTVBdRHTyF/), and submits a crashdump. The key error at the bottom is:

`/home/alan/.steam/debian-installation/steam.sh: line 772: 2249077 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER $DEBUGGER_ARGS "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"`

Further up, and more interestingly:

```
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadAtom (invalid Atom parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
Atom id in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  12
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadAtom (invalid Atom parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
Atom id in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  13
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadAtom (invalid Atom parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
Atom id in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  14
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
```

What can I do other than `steam --reset` to get steam working again?

Comment: Possibly this issue upstream. https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/7813

Comment: Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and check for a newer BIOS. Check if you've got the latest video driver. Edit your question and show me `free -h`. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: None of these things are useful for this issue.

Comment: Are you so sure? Since you haven't been able to fix it on your own, up to now, how can you completely dismiss other's suggestions for a few things to check? Have you tried logging into a different user account and see if Steam also crashes there? Etc.

Comment: These are all catch-all answers, used when nothing else works, typically. Running `steam --reset` "works", but fails again on next launch. The system doesn't have memory issues, I'm certain because it runs for months with very large memory hungry applications. It's likely a steam issue, not a hardware one.

Comment: They may be catch-all suggestions... but we have to start somewhere, don't we? See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348433/steam-wont-launch-on-ubuntu-20-04 applies to your situation. Or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286501/steam-crashes-on-ubuntu-20-10/1347721#1347721.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this is a [bug](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/7813) in steam, which is currently (as of 28/06/2021) only available in the beta builds of steam client. You need to launch steam to switch to the beta builds, and when it doesn't launch, that's tricky. So for the moment, do the following:

- Run `steam --reset`
- Login to steam
- If you use "family view" you may need to enter your pin
- In steam, go to Steam menu -> Settings -> Beta participation -> Change button
- In the "Beta Participation - Steam" window, change Beta participation drop-down from "NONE - Opt out of all beta programs" to "Steam beta update"

[image]

- Click OK

[image]

- Restart steam.
- Steam will download an update

[image]

- Steam will re-launch, into the beta.

Everything should work at this point. Feel free to opt back out of the beta once the above bug is in the stable release of steam client.